# could not detect right click mouse down and up events

Tags: c#, wpf

I have written a WPF software VS 2019 in Windows 7.
I want to achieve this function: when I right click a mouse down and draw a line in the canvas, a line will be drawn, starting at the point when I right click down a mouse and ending when I release the right click.

I have tried many method, but seems that the program could not detect the right click events.

```
<UserControl x:Class="STIGenericReport.UserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="407" Width="633" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" Focusable="False">
    <Grid Name="maingrid" Background="White" Height="405" Width="616" MinWidth="500">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="619*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height ="574*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="26" MinHeight="16" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Viewport3D Name="mainViewport" ClipToBounds = "False"  
                IsHitTestVisible="false"
                RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Margin="12,52,144,47">
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <OrthographicCamera x:Name="camera" Width="2"
                FarPlaneDistance="10"
                NearPlaneDistance="1" 
                LookDirection="0,0,-1"
                UpDirection="0,1,0"
                Position="0,0,2" />
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <Viewport3D.Children>
            <ModelVisual3D x:Name="Light1">
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="1, 1, -1" />
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D x:Name="Light2">
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="-1, 1, -1" />
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D x:Name="Light3">
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="0,-1,-0.5" />
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
        </Viewport3D.Children>
     </Viewport3D>

    <Canvas x:Name="canvasOn3D" Background="#00E6FFFF" 
            Margin="20,52,102,18"></Canvas>
    <Label Content="Trayinfo    &amp;" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="192,0,0,0" Name="lblTrayinfo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,257" Name="btn9" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,232" Name="btn8" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,149,0,207" Name="btn7" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,182" Name="btn6" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,157" Name="btn5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,132" Name="btn4" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,107" Name="btn3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,82" Name="btn2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,57" Name="btn1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,282" Name="btn10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,57" Name="lbl1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,82" Name="lbl2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,107" Name="lbl3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,132" Name="lbl4" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,157" Name="lbl5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,182" Name="lbl6" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,207" Name="lbl7" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,232" Name="lbl8" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,257" Name="lbl9" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,282" Name="lbl10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Content="Pacakage info" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Height="32" Name="lblPkgname" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="300,0,191,347" />
</Grid>
```

```
    private void OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)     
    {
        if (args.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)                
        {
            currentPoint = args.GetPosition(this);
        }
    }
    private void OnPreviewMouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)      
    {
        if (args.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Released)                  
        {      
            Line line = new Line();
            line.Stroke = SystemColors.WindowFrameBrush;
            line.X1 = currentPoint.X;
            line.Y1 = currentPoint.Y;
            line.X2 = currentPoint_2.X;
            line.Y2 = currentPoint_2.Y;
            line.StrokeThickness = 2;
            canvasOn3D.Children.Add(line);
         }
    }
```

When I debug this program, it does not enter into this function when I right click the mouse.

Comment: But left button works? Otherwise you might have forgotten to set the Canvas' Background property. It won't get mouse input with a null Background.

Comment: yes left button works

Comment: what do you mean by null background in my case?

Comment: The default `null` value, as opposed to Brushes.Transparent. What you are showing here should work. Is there any specific reason to use the Preview events?

Comment: First I used MouseRightButtonUp, but the event could not be detected so I use preview follow other answers in stackoverflow

Comment: But you have attached the handler methods? There is nothing like that in your XAML. Please help us to help you, by providing *all relevant details*.

Comment: You've laid out all your controls using margin, probably by dragging them round on the designer surface. This is a really bad way to work. You can easily have controls end up overlapping one another. You should use columns and rows in the grid to arrange stuff. With stackpanels to host a bunch of controls need to be lined up one after another.

Answer (score 0):

Previewmouserightbuttondown doesn't seem to work even in a simple experiment.

You also have some oddities in your code there.

The co-ordinates of your mouse should be based on the canvas ( presumably ).

Here's some simpler working markup and code.

In Mainwindow I just added a canvas inside the default Grid:

```
    <Grid>
        <Canvas 
            Name="lineCanvas"
            Background="Transparent"
            PreviewMouseDown="lineCanvas_PreviewMouseDown"
            PreviewMouseUp="lineCanvas_PreviewMouseUp"
                >
        
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

Notice I handle previewmousedown and up. The background of the canvas is set to transparent so it will be hit-testable.

My code ( which is working ):

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Point startPoint = new Point();

    private void lineCanvas_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
        {
            startPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(lineCanvas);
        }
    }

    private void lineCanvas_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (startPoint.X == 0 && startPoint.Y == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        var currentPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(lineCanvas);
        Line line = new Line();
        line.Stroke = SystemColors.WindowFrameBrush;
        line.X1 = startPoint.X;
        line.Y1 = startPoint.Y;
        line.X2 = currentPoint.X;
        line.Y2 = currentPoint.Y;
        line.StrokeThickness = 2;
        lineCanvas.Children.Add(line);

        startPoint = new Point();
    }
```

Note that in our map editor where I do a similar process for drawing straight lines I add a "rubber band" temporary line which follows the mouse round showing where the line will end up. This re-assures the user that something is happening. You might want to consider that approach.

Comment: PreviewMouseRightButtonDown/Up works fine for me. And there is no obvious reason why it should not.

Comment: Odd. Maybe driver dependent.

Comment: You have more than one canvas? What's that got to do with your question?